How to disable smooth animation for vertical tabs?
There is an update for 17.9 or maybe older, the code folder symbol turns to be "v" instead of of +. What's more, when going to a specific tab in the left vertical tabs, Visual Studio adds a smooth animation instead of instantly teleporting to the specific tab.
Can you disable the smooth animation?

Anyway to add an animated .gif of what you are talking about with the "smooth" animations?
